# Conflict in lexer rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 to parse a file, where elements can be the character `"b"` or simple literals, the problem appears when the Literal is just one character with a `"b"`.

Here's a simplified grammar

Lexer file:

```
B
    : 'b'
    ;

LETTER
    : [a-z]
    ;

LETTERS
    : LETTER+
    ;

Parser file:

pointer
    : B '.' LETTERS
    ;
```

`b.f` works but `b.b` doesn't, I get `"line 1:2 mismatched input 'b' expecting LETTERS"`. How can I avoid the conflict between the two lexical rules without putting Letter above B, where the problem will just change to `B`.

Comment: Why would it expect `LETTERS` at column 0? Also why does it say `Letters` with only a capital L? Are you sure you're running the same grammar you posted here?

Comment: Hi, I was testing with another grammar, this was the simplified version. I've just tested with this one and modified the question. Please notice the line "the problem appears when the Literal is just one character with a "b"".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the problem isn't just going to occur with `b`, but with any single letter. Letters other than `b` would simply be matched by the `LETTER` rule, which is still not the same as `LETTERS`. Since you never actually use `LETTER`, you can solve that part of the problem by simply removing `LETTER` from the grammar altogether.

As far as `B` is concerned, this is what's known as a contextual keyword: something that matches the rule for an identifier (or a `LETTERS` in this case), should be treated specially in some positions, but still be allowed as an identifier in other positions. The common way to implement contextual keywords is to define a non-terminal for identifiers that can either match an actual identifiers or any of the language's contextual keywords. So in your case, you could do this:

```
letters: LETTERS | B; // You can add "| LETTER" if you want to keep LETTER
pointer: B '.' letters;
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep LETTERS | B in the lexer file ?

Comment: @moe No. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could use modes and/or predicates to express things like "`B` can only be matched at the beginning of a line" or "`B` can't be matched after a dot", but there's no way to say "a `B` token should also be accepted where a `LETTERS` token is desired" in the lexer.